# How to make vertical switch-case like this?

Tags: plantuml

I want to create an activity diagram in `plantuml` with some operators selection `if elseif` (switch - case), which lead to 2 decisions. I created such diagram, but it has horizontal layout. 
What i get;

```
@startuml

start
:start;


if (some question) then (no)

elseif (some question) then (no)

elseif (some question) then (no)


else (yes)
 : decision 2;
stop

endif
: decision 1;
stop
@enduml
```

What i want:
[image: desired diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the `yes` following the `then` using nested `if`s, like this:

```
start
:start;

if (some question) then (yes)
  if (some question) then (yes)
    if (some question) then (yes)
      : decision 2;
      stop
    else (no)
    endif
  else (no)
  endif
else (no)
endif
: decision 1;
stop
```

That will give you :

[image: planuml sample server generated image]

This is using the [beta/new Activity Diagram Syntax](http://plantuml.com/activity-diagram-beta), as your example uses it.  I tried to use swimlanes and other features to move `decision 1` to the right or left.  But was not able to find anything that produced a better output.